# How to split a string into multiple paragraphs and storing the paragraph in a new row in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have been struggling with using regex in SQL.

Basically, I have a column which holds text, but each paragraph should be in a new row.

Example of a row from table message:

```
|  |AAA
|  |BBB
|1 |
|  |CCC
|  |DDD
```

I use the following sql code:

```
SELECT msg.id, regexp_substr(msg.text, '[^'||CHR(10)||CHR(10)||']+', 1, LEVEL) as text_p
FROM MSG
CONNECT BY regexp_substr(msg.text, '[^'||CHR(10)||CHR(10)||']+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL;
```

Where I want to get the following:

```
|1 |AAA
|  |BBB
|--|
|2 |CCC
|  |DDD
```

But I get the following:

```
|1 |AAA
|2 |BBB
|3 |CCC
|4 |DDD
```

I don't know why is this behavior, since when I try the regex on regexr.com, the selection with \n\n selects the paragraph space that I want to split, but the negation does not select the whole paragraph as a group (i.e. A's and B's as one, and C's and D's as another).

I tried using CHR(13)CHR(10), but it is still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regular expression `'[^'||CHR(10)||CHR(10)||']+'` has the meaning of any character that is not either `CHR(10)` or `CHR(10)` that is repeated one-or-more-times. It is identical to the expression `'[^'||CHR(10)||']+'`

What you want is to match zero-or-more characters, but as few as possible, `'(.*?)'` until you find either two new-line characters or the end of the string `'(' || CHR(10)||CHR(10)||'|$)'` and to output only that first capturing group:

```sql
SELECT msg.id,
       regexp_substr(
         msg.text,
         '(.*?)(' || CHR(10)||CHR(10)||'|$)',
         1,
         LEVEL,
         'n',    -- Allow . to match newlines
         1       -- Return the first capturing group
       ) as text_p
FROM   MSG
CONNECT BY
       LEVEL < REGEXP_COUNT(msg.text, '(.*?)(' || CHR(10)||CHR(10)||'|$)');
```

*Note: Use `<` rather than `<=` in the `CONNECT BY` clause as the regular expression will match a zero-width final term.*

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE msg (id, text) AS
SELECT 1, 'AAA
BBB

CCC
DDD' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ID | TEXT_P |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | AAA BBB |
| 1 | CCC DDD |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/lA69IDAX)